# recursion dilemma

Tags: java

I'm trying to create code to find the GCD of three user inputed numbers. My goal is to call the method with the inputed numbers, divide by q which is initialized as 1, record q only if the remainder is zero, then determine if its greater or equal to the smallest number, if it is not, increase q and recall method but if it is i would like to print out the largest last recorded q, what am i doing wrong? i keep getting stack overflow errors.

```
public static int recursiveMethod (int x, int y, int z, int q)
{
    int largestVar; 
    int xRes = x % q;
    int yRes = y % q;
    int zRes = z % q;
    if (xRes==0 && yRes ==0 && zRes==0) {
                largestVar = q;
                if (q >= x && q >= y && q >= z)
                {
                    return largestVar;
                }
    }
    else { 
           q++;
    }
   return recursiveMethod(x, y, z, q);
```

Comment: there is a limit on how many recursions you can do, this is limited by the stack depth. So i suggest you review your algorithm and if necessary turn it into an iterative one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first case will be 1, at which point, `xRes==0 && yRes ==0 && zRes==0` is surely true, and you set largestVar to 1.  Then, since 1  is probably less than the variables passed in, it continues, does not increment q in the else block, and calls `recursiveMethod` with q=1 again!  And the process repeats itself.

```
public static int recursiveMethod (int x, int y, int z, int q, int largestVar)
{
    int xRes = x % q;
    int yRes = y % q;
    int zRes = z % q;
    if (xRes==0 && yRes ==0 && zRes==0) {
    //A common denominator found!
                largestVar = q;
    }
    //regardless whether a denominator was found, check for the termination condition
    //Or works here, by the way, since we only need to know when q is greater than one of them.
    if (q >= x || q >= y || q >= z) {
        return largestVar;
    }
    //if we don't terminate, increment q and recurse. 
    q++;
    return recursiveMethod(x, y, z, q, largestVar);
}
```

Modified to correctly handle largestVar.  Wasn't paying attention to that bit.  Being locally scoped, the value of largestVar will not be maintained through recursive calls, so it must also be passed into the recursiveMethod call (either that, or be declared as a class scope variable, or some such).  An appropriate starting value for it would be 0.

Comment: thank you! i actually tried this code, but every time i tried to compile it, i kept getting "variable largestVar might not have been initialized". I also got a "missing return statement", which was supposed to be placed in the method, but outside the if/else statement

Comment: Modified to correctly handle `largestVar`.  Wasn't really thinking about that aspect of it at the time.

Answer (score 4):

One of the mistakes I noticed, your if condition is wrong:

```
if (q >= x && q >= y && q >= z)
```

GCD of these 3 numbers is less than or equal to each of them, so change it to:

```
if (x >= q && y >= q && z >= q)
```

If you are testing numbers iteratively like that, you should start from a certain number and countdown so that you can guarantee that a number meeting the condition is the actual GCD. And that certain starting number must be the **minimum of 3 numbers.** 
And fully working version of your method is here:

```
public static int recursiveMethod(int x, int y, int z, int q) 
{
    int largestVar;
    int xRes = x % q;
    int yRes = y % q;
    int zRes = z % q;
    if (xRes == 0 && yRes == 0 && zRes == 0) {
        largestVar = q;
        if (x >= q && y >= q && z >= q) {
            return largestVar;
        }
    } else {
        q--;
    }
    return recursiveMethod(x, y, z, q);
}
```

Sample call:

```
int x = recursiveMethod(30, 60, 45, 30); // x = 15 after this execution.
```

Comment: i changed the && to || for that, and it works fine! however, now I'm getting stackoverflow for the "xRes"

Comment: oh, i see. the way i'm going about this, is further complicating it. because i need this program to work with any random inputed numbers.

Comment: One note: if q is initialized as `min(x,y,z)` and decrements, `if (x >= q && y >= q && z >= q)` is assured to be true.  Could remove that if block and simply return there.

Comment: @femtoRgon you are ignoring the outside _if-block_.  recursiveMethod(30, 60, 45, 30) returns 15 and it is correct.

Comment: It gets the correct answer, absolutely, but the inner if block is trivially true, and unnecessary.  When `xRes == 0 && yRes == 0 && zRes == 0` you have the correct answer, with this iteration, and can immediately return a value.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that `gcd(x, y, z) = gcd(gcd(x, y), z).` So, if you want a simpler algorithm, you can implement gcd with two numbers and then call that method for 3 numbers.

```
public static int GCD(int x, int y) {
   if (y == 0) return x;
   return GCD(x, x % y);
}
```

And then for three numbers:

```
public static int GCDfor3 (int x, int y, int z) {
    return GCD(GCD(x, y), z)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are incrementing Q by one each time , with suitable numbers you will always run out of stack. I would use the euclidean algorithm for each pair of numbers and then start from there. I mean if it is common between a,b,c it must be common factor between a and b or a and c or c and b, right?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85830/how-to-use-the-extended-euclidean-algorithm-manually